# Using same template for regular pointer and shared pointer

Tags: c++

This one does not work. I wanted to reuse the template that I made for regular pointer. How can I use the same template for `std::shared_ptr`

```
class Base
{
public:
    int getVal() { return 0; }
};

template <class Type>
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type> entityPtr)
{
    if (entityPtr.size() == 0) return true;
    //...
    for (auto iter = entityPtr.begin(); iter != entityPtr.end(); iter++) {
        Type enPtr = *iter;
        int myval = enPtr->getVal();
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec_shared;
    std::vector<int*> vec_intp;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec_unique_ptr;
    writeRecordForSet(vec_shared);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_intp);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_unique_ptr);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Did you get an error message? If so, it would be helpful to include it in the question.

Comment: This will fail for `unique_ptr` because you're passing the vector by value to `writeRecordForSet` and creating more copies with `Type enPtr = *iter;`

Comment: And it fails for `int*` because there's not `getVal()` member for `int`.

Comment: With the `int*` version, I'm not sure what you expect `int* enPtr; enPtr->getVal();` to do. Did you mean to use `std::vector<Base*>` instead of `std::vector<int*>`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1

```
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type> entityPtr) { ... }
```

is a problem when the argument is of type `std::unique_ptr` since they cannot be copy constructed.

Change that to use a reference:

```
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type>& entityPtr) { ... }
```

or

```
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type> const& entityPtr) { ... }
```

#### Problem 2

In the function, you are assuming that the core object is of type `Base`.

```
for (auto iter = entityPtr.begin(); iter != entityPtr.end(); iter++) {
    Type enPtr = *iter;

    // Assuming that enPtr is a Base*, or shared_ptr<Base>, or unique_ptr<Base>
    int myval = enPtr->getVal();
}
```

If you use

```
std::vector<Base*> vec_intp;
```

instead of

```
std::vector<int*> vec_intp;
```

it will work.

Comment: I am passing entityPtr (std::vector) by reference in original code. "getVal" is also just to demonstrate the problem. I have more complex call inside the routine. It turns out that I had to copy the template, just because it is a std::vector of smart pointer instead of std::vector of regular pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy a `std::unique_ptr<>`, nor a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<>>`, so don't try that, but take the argument by reference (which you should to anyway; also use a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for clarity)

```
template <class Type>
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type> const&entityPtr)
{
    if (entityPtr.size() == 0) return true;
    for(const auto&enPtr : entityPtr) {
        auto myval = enPtr->getVal();
        /* ... */
    }    
    return true;
}
```

Of course, this will fail to compile if called for a `Type` that does not allow for `Type::getVal()` (such as your `vector<int*>` example). If you want your function to work for `Type`s that don't have such a getter, you can use a getter adaptation, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
inline auto getVal(T const&x) { return T::getVal(); }

inline int getVal(int*x) { return *x; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `getVal` [adaptor function to make it work](https://ideone.com/BlIG4y) and then write multiple overloads for your `int*`, `shared_ptr<Base>`, `unique_ptr<Base>`.

For example, `getVal` for `int*` could be as simple as:

```
int getVal(int*& p)
{
    return *p;
}
```

And then your `writeRecordForSet` should call `getVal` to get int value.

Full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    int getVal() { return 0; }
};

int getVal(shared_ptr<Base>& p)
{
    return p->getVal();
}

int getVal(unique_ptr<Base>& p)
{
    return p->getVal();
}

int getVal(int*& p)
{
    return *p;
}


template <class Type>
bool writeRecordForSet(std::vector<Type>& entityPtr)
{
    if (entityPtr.size() == 0)
        return true;
    //...
    for (auto iter = entityPtr.begin(); iter != entityPtr.end(); iter++) {
        int myval = getVal(*iter);
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec_shared;
    std::vector<int*> vec_intp;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec_unique_ptr;
    writeRecordForSet(vec_shared);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_intp);
    writeRecordForSet(vec_unique_ptr);
}
```